# WordPress Theme Logo Invisible and no Parallax on Pages with plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes, parallax

I have a website that works fine if a certain plugin (Business Listing) is not activated. But once the plugin is activated the logo disappears on the pages it's on. If you click and drag on the space where logo is suppose to be it will show itself temperately until mouse button is released. The same for the image with parallax effect. It shows on the page but with no parallax effect.

I can't find the conflicting code. Any advice?

www.newstralia.co.za

Comment: Your logo appearing function is based on JS as it has some animation effect. So it works fine on pages where you have no other JS based errors. on Directory pages you have JS errors you can see in the console.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a div that contains your image logo has zero opacity In Customize>>Custom CSS add this:

```
.pl-pro-version .pla-fade { 
  opacity: 1!important; 
}
```

For your parallax image I guess you need something like this (again in Customize>>Custom CSS):

```
.pl-bg-cover { 
  background-attachment: fixed; 
}
```

Consider that your image has small height and will stretch.